# Math.round MidPointRounding.AwayFromZero in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, math, rounding

I wanted to get the same result in javascript from this line in c#:

```
round = Math.Round((17245.22 / 100), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
// Outputs: 172.45
```

I've tried this but no success:

```
var round = Math.round(value/100).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: simply don't round, since you fix anyway: `(17245.22/100).toFixed(2)==172.45;`

Comment: I Believe that my answer also address this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60729374/6844481

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know that you are going to be diving by `100`, you can just round first then divide:

```
var round = Math.round(value)/100; //still equals 172.45
```

However, if you don't know what you are going to be diving with, you can have this more generic form:

```
var round = Math.round(value/divisor*100)/100; //will always have exactly 2 decimal points
```

In this case the `*100` will preserver 2 decimal points after the `Math.round`, and the `/100` move move them back behind the decimal.

Comment: This saves my life, tanks a lot :) the first piece of bits got the price :), thanks a lot

Comment: Incorrect answer javascript Math.round rounds towards +∞;
C# Math.Round((-17245.5 / 100), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) = -172.46;
js Math.round(-17245.5)/100 = -172.45